# Changing class name by id tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the name of a class by grabbing it's id. So with the following HTML I want to pick up the `id=section1` and change the class name from `breadcrumb` to `active breadcrumb`.

```
<div class="breadcrumb" id="section1">
  <div class="breadcrumb-icon"></div><span class="breadcrumb-label">Appearance</span>
</div>
```

I've tried the following, but I cannot see a way to change the class name.

```
$('#section1').addClass('active breadcrumb').removeClass('breadcrumb');
```

also I've tried:

```
$('#section1').toggleClass( "active" );
```

I tried the suggestions in the answers, but still no joy. Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/U9Ahr/3/

Comment: Try `$('#section1').addClass("active");`

Comment: That should work, unless you used the id `section1` more than once.

Comment: ^^ likely culprit, as adding a class that is already there wouldn't be a problem, and the active class should be added with the code in the question, unless there's invalid markup or issues with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset your classes and set the new group of classes to it like below,

```
$('#section1').removeClass().addClass('active breadcrumb')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HPut9/)

If your case is to invoke the class manipulation for one time, Then you can go for

```
$('#section1').addClass('active');
```

Because while seeing your html structure, You are already having a class `active` for that element which is with ID `selection1`. But keep in mind that, if you have to call this invoking for many times then this will append many more duplicate classes with that particular element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the class name to be `active breadcrumb` then this will do it:

```
$('#section1').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Run`document.querySelectorAll("#section1")` and check if you only got one div in the resulting NodeList. If you have more, you have invalid markup and jQuery doesn't support that. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying with just the HTML shown above, so there should only be one id=section1

Comment: Well, that code is fine, you just forgot to include jQuery... See http://jsfiddle.net/U9Ahr/4/